# Is there a way to use a vector in coalesce function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a number of variables that I want to coalesce together in R. I have extracted them into a vector to use them in the coalesce function. Typing each one of them in the function is a bit tedious. Is there a way to go about it?

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(c(NA, 1, 3), 10, replace = T),
  var2 = sample(c(NA, 1, 3), 10, replace = T),
  var3 = sample(c(NA, 1, 3), 10, replace = T),
  var4 = sample(c(NA, 1, 3), 10, replace = T),
  age = floor(rnorm(10, 15, 2)),
  gender = factor(round(runif(10, 1, 2)),
              labels = c("Male", "Female"))
)

# Desired variables

myvars <- df %>% select(contains("var")) %>% names()


df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(finalvar = coalesce(myvars))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluate with `!!!` and unpack with `rlang::syms`:

```
df %>%
   mutate(finalvar = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(myvars)))
```

Or directly attaching `rlang`:

```
library(rlang)
df %>%
   mutate(finalvar = coalesce(!!! syms(myvars)))
```

Both Output:

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4 age gender finalvar
1     3    1   NA   NA  14 Female        3
2     3    1   NA    3  17 Female        3
3     3   NA    3    3  14   Male        3
4     1    1    1   NA  12 Female        1
5     3    3    3    3  13 Female        3
6     1   NA    1    1  16 Female        1
7     1    3   NA   NA  14   Male        1
8     1    3    1    3  12   Male        1
9     3   NA    3   NA  13   Male        3
10   NA   NA    1   NA  14   Male        1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `invoke`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(finalvar = invoke(coalesce, across(all_of(myvars))))
   var1 var2 var3 var4 age gender finalvar
1     3    1   NA   NA  14 Female        3
2     3    1   NA    3  17 Female        3
3     3   NA    3    3  14   Male        3
4     1    1    1   NA  12 Female        1
5     3    3    3    3  13 Female        3
6     1   NA    1    1  16 Female        1
7     1    3   NA   NA  14   Male        1
8     1    3    1    3  12   Male        1
9     3   NA    3   NA  13   Male        3
10   NA   NA    1   NA  14   Male        1
```

Comment: FYI: "invoke() is retired in favour of the simpler exec() function reexported from rlang. exec() evaluates a function call built from its inputs and supports tidy dots"

Comment: @camille yes, i know that, but there are some cases exec doesn't work which invoke does.  Just like when `plyr` is retired, people still use some of its functions because the ones that should be a replacement is more general and codewise lengthy

Comment: @camille Also IMHO, using the `!!` and stuff in exec makes the code a bit difficult to read though because `!!` in `base R` can be read differently and gives completely different results.  For a newbie in R, getting used to splice options take time

Comment: I agree, it's just something to make a note of, especially for functions or libraries that are no longer being maintained